# Error in BFTaskCompletionSource.h in ShareKit iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, sharekit

I am using cocoapods first time and trying to run the Demo Sharekit app.Here is the link
https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit-Demo-App

I installed the pod before running .xcworkspace and when i compile it is giving me compile error.

Here is the screenshot of error.
https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/11598940/12723455/68131df8-c8be-11e5-958d-9433a3ca5e65.png

I mean it is a demo app and it should run.What i am doing wrong.Any idea?

Comment: Are you running the right target? "ShareKit Demo App (CocoaPods)" or "ShareKit Demo App"?

Comment: @BarbaraRodeker Yes right now i am running "ShareKit Demo App (CocoaPods)" and getting this error.. As far i have heard i have to run this.
But i have also tried running the "ShareKit Demo App"...That also resulted in error.

Comment: Plus i have tried this on Xcode 5.1.1 and Xcode 6.3... Do you think this can be a issue? But it should have run on Xcode 6.3 i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@saad_nad, I have downloaded Share Kit, and followed the instructions for running the demo target "**ShareKit Demo App (CocoaPods)**", it's running perfectly on XCode 7.2 (7C68) but I got the same errors as you on older Xcode 6.0.1. I do not have XCode 6.3 to give it a try, but as far as I know the problem could be related to nullability annotations and those are supported from XCode 6.3: [Objective-C extensions on XCode release 6.3](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH4-SW26), so as you said it should run on that version... but for some reason Bolts pod team recommends 6.3.2.

My answer would be to update your XCode version to the latest 7.2 in case Bolts pods is making use of another feature supported from version higher than XCode 6.3.
Here's the recommendation I mentioned from Bolts team to upgrade to XCode 7.2 or at least support XCode 6.3.2: [Bolts using nullability annotations](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-ObjC/issues/122)

Comment: Yes i think this is the issue.Because i just tried ShareKit 2.0 on Xcode 5.1.1 at least it got compiled. Looks like i have to upgrade ..Thanks this seems to be the correct answer.